# Animate property in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

Lets say I have the property

```
public double MyProp{get;set;}
```

How can I animate that property to go from 0 to 100 in 1 second? I have tried things like:

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 100, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
animation.BeginAnimation(MyProp, ???);
```

---

### Edit

On my view I have:

```
<Image Name="ImgCompassPointer" Source="somePath" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>                    
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding MyProp}"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

When ever I set a new value for the angle I want to animate it. How can I do that on code behind?

### Note

If I where to be animating the Height then I would be able to do something like:

```
 DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 100, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
 ImgCompassPointer.ImgCompassPointer.BeginAnimation(Image.HeightProperty, animation);
```

But I cannot figure out a way to animate the rotation/angle property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate `rotation/angle` by using

```
var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(360, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
image.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
image.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, doubleAnimation);
```